# Active graphics card Unknown after upgrade to Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, nvidia, optimus

*Situation:* I have upgraded two Nvidia Optimus laptops from Linux Mint 17.3 to version 18.

*Problem:* After upgrade, Nvidia Optimus does not work, both laptops booted into Cinnamon fallback mode.

*Temporary solution:* I changed the graphics driver to Nouveau, then the Cinnamon works, but there is an "X" icon in system tray indicating Active graphics card: Unknown. And I obviously need a "real" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get purge bbswitch*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Afterwards, run `driver-manager`, install the Nvidia proprietary driver and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem for me. I deinstalled the microcode driver for intel CPU in driver manager. And after reboot - thats it.