# Missing active graphics card indicator

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, optimus

*Situation:* I have upgraded two Nvidia Optimus laptops from Linux Mint 17.3 to version 18.

*Problem:* After upgrade, and [a fix for Nvidia drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297738/active-graphics-card-unknown-after-upgrade-to-linux-mint-18), I miss the applet in system tray indicating, which graphics card is currently in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I found out, it is a separate package called `nvidia-prime-applet`.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime-applet
```

and enabling it in Applets (one of Mint's configuration application).